# Alternate codes for ExecuteReader

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

It is my first time to post here. My question is what code can we use instead of ExecuteReader? We're currently doing a total production program and we want to input the productions, Projects 1-4 (I label it P1-P4) into the text box, but i have read that ExecuteReader is only for SQL, we're only using Access DB. [Our code for displaying the projects to textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeP10.png)

Comment: Please don't post links to code.  Post the relevant code directly and format it appropriately.  If it feels like too much code to post in a question here then that means that you haven't spent enough time refining your question.

Comment: The problem is not that of `ExecuteReader` The problem here seems to be related to the use of the correct driver. ExecuteReader is a pattern that is supported for all databases.

Answer (score 3):

You apparently don't know what "SQL" is.  SQL (structured query language) is not a database.  It is a language that databases use to define and manipulate data.  Just about all databases use SQL for this purpose, including Access.

There are a number of databases with "SQL" in the name, e.g. SQL Server, MySQL and SQLite, but there's no database named "SQL".  Some people lazily refer to Microsoft's SQL Server as just SQL or maybe MS SQL but its name is SQL Server.

As for using `ExecuteReader`, it's for any database.  If you were connecting to SQL Server then you'd use a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` object and call `ExecuteReader` on that.  As you're using Access, you need to use a `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand` and call `ExecuteReader` on that.  They both work the same way but the different providers are for different data sources.